# How to make a part of picture transparent in Photoshop Elements?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I am a beginner in photo editing. I want to make a particular part of image transparent in PS Elements. I have attached the source image and result image. You can see that left part of the result image is transparent.

[image: Source Image]

[image: Result Image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a [layer mask](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop-elements/using/layer-masks.html).

The mask can either be on this layer, creating an opening for a layer below; or it can be on the photo, constraining the photo to the triangular area.

Comment: What is the process? Can we do the same in Snagit?